# Remove Server response header from nginx with alpine base container

Tags: nginx, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am using a nginx alpine based image and I want to remove the `Server` response header. Note that I already used `server_tokens off;` but this only removes the nginx version.

I have something like this:

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /app;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /META-INF {
       deny all;
    }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21.3-alpine
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

If you can also provide a working configuration that would be great.